# How to verify fields inside a .txt file in Java?

Tags: java, csv, file-io, nio, file-handling

I have a .txt file which i want to read using Java and then verify if some particular fields is equal to a given string.

Now, i want to validate that if line/record starts with 03, then see of 7th index field is '0420'. Also, if its an empty field, then verify it.

```
public class ReadFile {
    public static List<String> lines;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        readFileIntoList("File1.txt");
        String s1 = lines.get(0).subString(0,7)
        if(s1.equals("0420")){
            sop(s1);
        }
    }

    public static List<String> readFileIntoList(String file) {
        lines = Collections.emptyList();
        try {
            lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            for (String s : lines) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return lines;
    }
}
```

File1.txt

```
01,23434,34343,6335,1235533,345,,,42/
02,TEST23,2253434,1,2233,2233,,4/
03,TEST44,,1123,3434343,,,0420,3434,,,/
04,2343,24334,Test2,1600819,4802458,3201638,NOTE1,TEXT2,
66,MORE TEXT IN THIS LINE
04,2343443,24334,Test2,1600819,4802458,3201638,NOTE122,TEXT2,
```

Comment: You've described what you are building. I'm missing your code and a question about that code. Please edit your question and add these things

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, I have added some code. Please look into it.

Comment: I want to store all lines in a List<String>, then split on the comma. Store individual fields and then see if any field matches a particular string or contains a string.

Comment: @nick235 seems like you're basically already halfway there. What problem are you having? As an aside, you should avoid catching an exception and do nothing with it. At least log the fact that the exception happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String col_0 = "03";
    String col_7 = "0420";
    
    boolean matchedFound = false;
    
    List<String> readAllLines = readFileIntoList();
    for (int i = 0; i < readAllLines.size(); i++) {
        String[] splittedLine = readAllLines.get(i).split(",");
        if(splittedLine.length >= 7) {
            String firstWord = splittedLine[0];
            if(firstWord.equals(col_0)) {
                String seventhWord = splittedLine[7];
                if(seventhWord.equals(col_7)) {
                    matchedFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(matchedFound);
}
```